# configure Castle Windosor and generic

Tags: castle-windsor

this is my code in Global.asax

```
 WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
                                       .ImplementedBy(typeof(NHRepository<>))
                                       .LifeStyle.Transient)
```

I've tried to translate it in a xml config file with this but didn't work

```
<component id="NHRepository"
           service="NCommon.Data.IRepository'1, NCommon"
           type="NCommon.Data.NHibernate.NHRepository'1, NCommon.NHibernate"
           lifestyle="transient">
</component>
```

How can I convert this code in a config file as Windsor.config ?

Tanks
Mirko

Comment: See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934352/castle-windsor-fluent-api-define-array-with-single-item-as-dependency)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent), not [apostrophes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe)

```
<component id="NHRepository"
           service="NCommon.Data.IRepository`1, NCommon"
           type="NCommon.Data.NHibernate.NHRepository`1, NCommon.NHibernate"
           lifestyle="transient">
</component>
```

Comment: Good one. I didn't notice it ;)