# Castle NHibernate Integration - Creating a generic configurationBuilder

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am using Nhibernate 3.0.0.1001 and Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration 1.1.0.0

I am using Castle to inject an ISessionManager into my session management classes.

I am specifying My ConfigurationBuilder in the web.config like this:

```
   <castle>
   <facilities>
   <facility id="MyNhibernateFacility"
    type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility, Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration"
    isWeb="false"
    configurationBuilder="MyDomainModelAssembly.ConfigurationBuilder, MyDomainModelAssembly">
      <factory id="nhibernate.factory">
        <settings>
          <item key="show_sql">true</item>
          <item key="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</item>
          <item key="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</item>
          <item key="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</item>
          <item key="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial
           Catalog=MyDb;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true</item>
          <item key="proxyfactory.factory_class">
          NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,  
          NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</item>
         </settings>
      </factory>
    </facility>
```

My "ConfigurationBuilder" class looks like this:

```
 public class ConfigurationBuilder : IConfigurationBuilder
   {
       public Configuration GetConfiguration(IConfiguration facilityConfiguration)
       {
           var defaultConfigurationBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
           var configuration =  
           defaultConfigurationBuilder.GetConfiguration(facilityConfiguration);

          return Fluently.Configure(configuration)
            .Mappings(ConfigureMappings)
            .BuildConfiguration();
      }

    public void ConfigureMappings(MappingConfiguration mappingConfiguration)
    {
        mappingConfiguration.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyModelClass>()
            .Conventions.Add(
                ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"),
                PrimaryKey.Name.Is(n => "Id"),
                DefaultCascade.None(),
                new HiLoPrimarykeyConvention());
    }

    public class HiLoPrimarykeyConvention : IIdConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
        {
            instance.GeneratedBy.HiLo("1000");
        }
    }
   }
```

I would like to make the ConfigurationBuilder more generic so that it does not have a dependency on the models it maps to.

So instead of:

```
 .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyModelClass>().
```

I would like to say something like:

```
.AddFromAssemblyOf<T>().
```

I can do this in the ConfigurationBuilder class

**but is there then any way of specifying what "T" is in the web.config facility?**

For example I know I can't do this:

```
  <castle>
   <facilities>
   <facility ...
  configurationBuilder="MyGenericNhibernateSessionManagementAssembly.
  ConfigurationBuilder<MyModelClass>, MyGenericNhibernateSessionManagementAssembly">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [configure Castle Windosor and generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272104/configure-castle-windosor-and-generic)

Comment: Hi Stuart, hows it going?! thanks but I think that is abit different. Im trying to avoid having to specify the model in the configuration builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! this is how to do it:

in your configuration builder:

```
  public class ConfigurationBuilder<T> :
  ...
  public static void ConfigureMappings(MappingConfiguration mappingConfiguration)
   {
        mappingConfiguration.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>()
```

Then in your web.config

```
<castle>
<facilities>
<facility ...
   configurationBuilder="MyGenericNhibernateSessionManagementAssembly.
   ConfigurationBuilder`1[[YourModelsAssembly.AModel, YourModelsAssembly]],  
   MyGenericNhibernateSessionManagementAssembly">
```